# I want to perform a count of customers with delinquent accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2005 and I am trying to filter our duplicate customer names when running a count on delinqent customers. I have the delinquent contract numbers are set to 0-30-60-90-120-150-180 baskets, but some customers have multiple contracts in delinquency and I do want to count them twice.

```
Select 
(Case
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 180 Then 180
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 150 Then 150
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 120 Then 120
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 90 Then 90
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 60 Then 60
    When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 30 Then 30
END) AS Fed_Dlq_Bucket, Count(dbo.customer.cust_name) AS CountOfCustomer_name, Count(dbo.contract.contract_id) AS CountOfcontract_id 
From dbo.contract INNER JOIN dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields ON dbo.contract.contract_id = dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.contract_id 
WHERE (((v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP) Like '00000001' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000002' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000011' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000012' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000021' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000031' Or (v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.RELATIONSHIP)='00000041') AND ((v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.BLENDED_NET_INVEST)>0) AND ((contract.contract_status) Is Null Or (contract.contract_status)<>88))
GROUP BY 
    (Case
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 180 Then 180
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 150 Then 150
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 120 Then 120
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 90 Then 90
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 60 Then 60
        When dbo.v_opened_contract_dropped_fields.days_past_due >= 30 Then 30
    END)
ORDER BY Fed_Dlq_Bucket;
```

I want to see the filtered amount of delinquent customers in each bucket with no repeat customer names. All help is appreciated! When I add this join, my totals go up, not down..which I can't figure out.

```
Inner Join dbo.customer ON dbo.v_contract_all.customer_name = dbo.customer.cust_name
```

Comment: How about some ddl and sample data. sqlfiddle.com can help.

Answer (score 0):

Some sample data to maybe help figure out a way around the issue.

```
DECLARE @Contract TABLE
(
    CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(10),
    DAYS_PAST_DUE INT
)

INSERT INTO @Contract
VALUES
( 'Fred', 100 ),
( 'George', 20 ),
( 'Mac', 30 ),
( 'Cheese', 40 ),
( 'Fred', 100 ),
( 'Blue', 50 ),
( 'Oswald', 60 ),
( 'Herman', 70 ),
( 'Fred', 100 ),
( 'Betty', 80 ),
( 'Wilma', 90 ),
( 'Oswald', 60 ),
( 'Barney', 190 );
```

I put Fred in there several times because Wilma has been using his charge card alot.

```
WITH T AS
(
    SELECT *,
        (CASE 
            When days_past_due >= 180 Then 180
            When days_past_due >= 150 Then 150
            When days_past_due >= 120 Then 120
            When days_past_due >= 90 Then 90
            When days_past_due >= 60 Then 60
            When days_past_due >= 30 Then 30
            ELSE 0
        END) Fed_Dlq_Bucket,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.CUSTOMER_NAME ORDER BY c.DAYS_PAST_DUE DESC) RN
    FROM @Contract c
)
```

Here I make a CTE to try to figure out the past due bucket for each row, I also partition the row based on the customer name so if there is duplicates, I'm only going to look at the first row of each set.

```
SELECT Fed_Dlq_Bucket,
    COUNT(*) NumOfDelinquents
FROM T
WHERE T.RN = 1
GROUP BY T.Fed_Dlq_Bucket
```

I sum up the buckets and spit out the totals:

```
Fed_Dlq_Bucket  NumOfDelinquents
0   1
30  3
60  3
90  2
180 1
```

Maybe you can use partition to clear out those dupes and get your counts easier? Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Kevin for the answer, but I am getting a syntax error when I am adding my FROM and WHERE statements. I have multiple tables to query and certain conditions that have to be met to be counted. I'm getting the error at the end of the first SELECT statement.